# Populate textbox data to other forms' textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a ‘Login’ Form that opens when accessing database. It includes a textbox 'txtLoginID' bound to LoginID field in Employee table which has another field name called Fullname. On clicking OK button, a main form is opened. So far it’s OK.

I am trying to populate the textbox data to other form or subform's textbox to show the Fullname of the employee. I’ve put that other form textbox

`controlsource=ReturnUser()` ReturnUser is is public Function that is coded like that:

```
Public Function ReturnUser() As String
ReturnUser = DLookup("Fullname", "Employees", "loginID=" & Forms!Login!txtLoginID)
End Function
```

Still can’t get txtLoginId populated to other form’s textbox. I appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

> a textbox 'txtLoginID' bound to LoginID field in Employee table

That won't work. Make the textbox *unbound* and call your function in the AfterUpdate event of the textbox.

Comment: Thanks for reply Gustav. I made textbox bound to get other filed in table Employee. Secondly, poulating textbox data is not required Afterupdate, it is required on open other forms to

Comment: We don't have your application, so it is a little hard to figure out what you are doing.